# Animation show hide layout in bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have xml file :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
        android:text="Hide" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#a70000"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and now I want click button show/hide to show/hide layout2.
I used code :

```js
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ln2.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                    ln2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ln2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.translate_in));
                }
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ln2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    ln2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ln2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.translate_out));
                }
            }
        });
```

and my animation

```html
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="350"
        android:fromYDelta="100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

animation_out.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="350"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

but when layout2 show I show a pace in bottom before show layout2 same : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wDMk.png)

How I can fix it? I trie user set layout param for layout1 when show hide layout2 but it not working.
Thank you very much!

Comment: It works perfect for me. Try to run in real device. All animations are working perfect.

Comment: I test in reak device, some time my bug sometime appears, and in fact I user webview replace layout1, so bug show always